# How to create page with different forms in view(yii2)?

Tags: php, yii2

For example:

We have table `book` with different types (`Horror`, `Travel`, `History`).

We need to create a method `update` for these books, but for each book type we need to show different type of form.

How can we achieve this?

**Is the following code correct?**

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->getType($id);

    switch ($model->type){
        case Book::TYPE_HORROR:
            return $this->render('update_horror', [
                'model' => $model
            ]);
            break;
        case Book::TYPE_TRAVEL:
            return $this->render('update_travel', [

            ]);
            break;
        case Book::TYPE_HISTORY:
            return $this->render('update_history', [

            ]);
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it something like this

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->getType($id);

    return $this->render('update_'. $model->type, ['model' => $model]);

}
```

where view name have to be "update_" + exactely $model->type result,

eg: horror = update_orror.php

This is for reneder the view, but do not forget to add action method to your form, otherwise it will look for a page that doesn't exist.

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['action' =>['book/update']])
```